# Socket.io error with NGINX when deploying a MERN app with Docker

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, nginx, digital-ocean

I have a MERN app deployed on digitalocean with docker. Backend and frontend seem good but for some reason the Websocket, socket.io connection fails on the deployed application.

error message:
[image]

I use *http-proxy-middleware*, my *setupProxy.js* file: *(main-be is the name of container)*

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function (app) {
  app.use(
    '/api',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: 'http://main-be:5001',
      changeOrigin: true,
    })
  );
};
```

*frontend/src/utils/axios.js*:

```
import axios from 'axios';
export const baseURL = 'https://example.com';
export default axios.create({ baseURL });
```

*frontend/src/utils/constants.js*:

```
const API_BASE_ORIGIN = 'wss://46.111.119.161';
export { API_BASE_ORIGIN };
```

...here i tried these but none worked:

```
const API_BASE_ORIGIN = 'https://example.com';
const API_BASE_ORIGIN = 'ws://46.111.119.161:5001';
const API_BASE_ORIGIN = 'ws://46.111.119.161'; 
const API_BASE_ORIGIN = 'wss://46.111.119.161'; 
const API_BASE_ORIGIN = 'wss://46.111.119.161:5001';
```

part of *socketContext.js*:

```
  //* socket connection
  useEffect(() => {

    const newSocket = socketIo.connect(API_BASE_ORIGIN, {
      transports: ['websocket'],
    });
    setSocket(newSocket);
    if (!newSocket) return;
    newSocket.on('connect', () => {
      console.log(`Hurrah Socket ${newSocket.id} Connected`);
    });
  }, []);
```

NGINX *default.conf* config file:

```
upstream api {
    server main-be:5001;
}

upstream client {
    server main-fe:3000;
}



server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name _;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# main server block
server {
  listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;

  server_name _;

  # enable subfolder method reverse proxy confs
  include /config/nginx/proxy-confs/*.subfolder.conf;

  # all ssl related config moved to ssl.conf
  include /config/nginx/ssl.conf;

  client_max_body_size 0;


   
     location / {
        proxy_pass http://client;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }


     location /api {
        proxy_pass http://api;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

    }
      location /ws/ {
        proxy_pass http://client;
            
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the actual error in the *network* tab of the inspector?

Comment: Can't really see anything in the _network tab_. Just the _Request_ _URL_ s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution:

- add `WDS_SOCKET_PORT=0` to the React frontend **.env** file. (*so it will not add an unnecessary additional port*)
- edit the nginx default.conf config file to this (it's not the whole file):

  ```
  location /socket.io {
    proxy_pass http://api;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $host; }
  ```

*setupProxy.js* file:

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function (app) {
  app.use(
    '/api',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: 'http://main-be:5001',
      changeOrigin: true,
    })
  );
};
```

*frontend/src/utils/axios.js:*

```
import axios from 'axios';
export const baseURL = 'https://example.com';
export default axios.create({ baseURL });
```

*frontend/src/utils/constants.js:*

```
const API_BASE_ORIGIN = 'https://example.com';
export { API_BASE_ORIGIN };
```